# question about sending mail with ipad

Tags: ipad, email, networking

I have an ipad app, that sends confirmation data to sms and email, its working fine, but the question is [hope is not to stupid] 
* who is the network responsible for sending this mail?, as it goes out of the device via wifi, which mailer company is being used?, does it have a limit of mails to send in a period of time?

thanks a lot!

edit
* using the  built-in mail UI 
* and messageComposer for mail as well
cheers

Comment: Are you using the built-in mail UI or some other scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mail goes out on the account that the user selects -- it's an option in the messaging UI that appears.

And the messaging rate is limited by how often your user is prepared to press the "Send" button. I don't think iOS has a limit, but if you're sending messages to a lot of people some mail servers will throttle the rate of sending. But this shouldn't affect your app as iOS sends messages in the background.